# How to make vscode navigate generated python files from bazel?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, code-generation, bazel

I'm curious if anyone has any tips and techniques for navigating to definitions and modules that are generated code and referenced from python modules checked into the repo. I'm basically looking for a streamlined experienced for code navigation as it pertains to that code present in the bazel cache.

To give a concrete example

```py
# my_in_repo_source.py

from my.generated.code.module import generated_symbol
```

The goal is to be able to command click the symbol `generated_symbol` and jump down into the bazel cache and locate the definition.

By way of analogy, C++ has the so called `includePath` setting that can be configured in `c_cpp_properties.json` which can include things like the bazel convenience symlinks of `bazel-bin`, `bazel-generated`, etc.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference

Answer (score 0):

Looks like on the python half of vscode there is an analogous mechanism like found in C++, which is the `include` option documented at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference#_code-analysis-settings

> Paths of directories or files that should be included in analysis.
> If no paths are specified, Pylance defaults to the directory that contains the workspace root.
> Paths may contain wildcard characters such as ** (a directory or multiple levels of directories), * (a sequence of zero or more characters), or ? (a single character).

It appears like the settings can be configured at `@ext:ms-python.vscode-pylance include`

[image: vscode Python > Analysis settings]